# ¿Como puedo comprobar si un número es capicúa?

Tags: python, funciones

Necesito escribir en Python una función que devuelva el valor booleano `True` si el número es capicúa, de lo contrario devuelve el valor booleano `False`.
En caso de que el parámetro no sea de tipo entero, debe retornar nulo.
Recibe un numero: Será el número sobre el que se evaluará si es capicúa o no lo es.

```
def numeroCapicua(numero):
    if numero == type(int):
        str(numero)
        numeroinvertido=numero[::-1]
        numero1=int(numeroinvertido)
        if numero1 == numero:
            return(True)
        else:
            return(False)
    else:
        return("no ingreso un numero entero")
```

Estoy haciéndolo de esta forma, pero cuando convierto el parámetro en `str` automáticamente me pasa al primer `else` y me da que el parámetro no es un número entero.

Comment: estimado aquí no hacemos las tareas de los demas.

Comment: Hola Francisco, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, resuélvanlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

Answer (score 0):

La conversión de un tipo a otro en Python no funciona como crees.
La línea `str(numero)` no hace que la variable `numero` sea una string.
Lo que hace es devolver la variable `numero` en formato string.
Por lo tanto necesitas asignar este valor a alguna variable.
En tu caso supongo que lo que pretendes hacer es `numero = str(numero)`.
Al tener el número en formato de string, ya podemos usar la notación `[::-1]` para darle la vuelta.
Podemos hacer la comparación en string, no es necesario volverlo a convertir a entero.

Hay algo más que cambiar en tu función.
Según el enunciado, si el valor introducido no es un entero, debe devolver nulo.
Tú estás devolviendo una string, que no es lo que se te ha pedido.
Normalmente esto se maneja emitiendo un `TypeError`.
En ese error puedes escribir un mensaje como el que tienes en tu código.

Otra recomendación es que evites que el código principal tenga un nivel de indentación sólo por el chequeo del tipo del argumento.
Es mejor que hagas las comprobaciones pertinentes y el cuerpo de la función sea independiente.

Aplicando todas las recomendaciones:

```
def numeroCapicua(numero):
    if not isinstance(numero, int):
        # raise TypeError("No ingreso un numero entero")
        return None
    numero = str(numero)
    return numero == numero[::-1]
```